# Is there any way to use class without inheriting from ApiController, use as api controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I know solution like I want in [ASP.NET Boilerplate](http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/). In this framework you can declare classes, inherit from custom class ( not inherited from ApiController ) and when it's run, it builds controllers and works like controllers.

But I write my application from scratch and actually I don't know how it works in Boilerplate ( I think it use refactoring, I found ControllerBuilder classes, but it's so big library, I don't think it's good idea to rewrite same code or copy past it, there are so many dependencies ).

I know I can handle requests and response with my custom classes methods, but I think it will work a little bit slowly and not safely.

Maybe you know a simple way to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is technically possible but in no way would it be simple. In fact, if you are dead set on this I would suggest that you may not want to use the Web-Api framework at all.

However, to address the question of being possible, I would start by looking at leveraging `HttpRoutingDispatcher` as an extension point. An overview of the pipeline including the dispatcher can be found here: http://byterot.blogspot.com/2012/05/aspnet-web-api-series-messagehandler.html

Once you come up with the right place to extend the web api pipeline, you will still need to create the component(s) which will somehow "know" how to invoke your non-controllers - and you will be losing most of what the framework has to offer (action resolution, parameter binding, action filters, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Use Controller to render your normal views. ApiController action only return data that is serialized and sent to the client.

here is the [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Quote:

> Note If you have worked with ASP.NET MVC, then you are already
>   familiar with controllers. They work similarly in Web API, but
>   controllers in Web API derive from the ApiController class instead of
>   Controller class. The first major difference you will notice is that
>   actions on Web API controllers do not return views, they return data.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I mean. I don't want to inherit from any type of controllers ( ApiController or ControllerBase ). I want to use free from ASP platform classes as controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit from ApiController because it has the built in request/response pipeline/cycle.